# how to post mulitple data through json posting?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

```
var post = { "ID":1 };

var step = [1,2,3,4,5];

post.step = step;

console.log(post)

$.ajax({
    url:'rss/test',
    type:'POST',
    data:post
})
```

-

```
 public JsonResult Test(int ID, IEnumerable<string> step)
 {
     return Json(true);
 }
```

I want to post it through JSON, how can I do this? When I tried to do this I found that this did not work. The step are not worked (or post)

**update:** after setting it to

```
var post  = {
"ID":1,
step:[{'Name':'first'},{'Name':'second'}]
}

$.post("/rss/test",post,function(){
});

public JsonResult Test(int ID, IEnumerable<string> step)
        {
            return Json(true);
        }
```

i feel it's work but i got result

```
step
Count = 2
    [0]: null
    [1]: null
```

in immediate window.

so i hope i am go in right direction but both thing are null. now someone can help me to get them work.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data types on the server don't match the object's your sending from your client. Try this.

```
public class Post
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Step { get; set; } 
}
```

Then in your controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Test(Post post)
{

}
```

You have to check it though, didn't compile it.

To post the data you have to set the dataType properly:

```
$.ajax({
  url:'rss/test',
  type:'POST',
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json",
  data:post
})
```

Comment: Passing as JS object are the properties that bound to the Action parameters. Your approach will work too :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `traditional` parameter

```
$.ajax({
    url:'rss/test',
    type:'POST',
    data:post,
    traditional: true
})
```